# Are nested quantifers natural to think about?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

If someone claims

> there are objects *a* and *b* such that *P*(*a*, *b*) holds,

then I interpret this as

> there is tuple *a*, *b* of objects such that *P*(*a*, *b*).

However, in first-order logic one would express the above statement as

> there is an *a* for which there is a *b* such that *P*(*a*, *b*).

The quantifiers here are nested.

Also, if someone claims

> For any two objects *a*, *b*, *Q*(*a*, *b*) holds,

then I interpret this as

> for any combination of objects *a*, *b*, *Q*(*a*, *b*) holds.

However, in first order logic one would express this as a nested quantifer "for all *a*, it is true that for all *b*, *Q*(*a*, *b*)".

My question is: Do these nested quantifier formulations really reflect human thought, or is it just an encoding? If one was to develop a formal system that is nearer to the way we actually think about it, should one introduce "multi-ary quantifiers" such as "for all a, b" and "exists a, b", or are these expressions naturally understood as nested quantifiers?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think maybe P (a,b) is not first order logic.  what is the meaning of ","?

Comment: @mobileink It is standard for non-logical symbols (predicates and functions) with valence, that the comma is used to separate arguments.

Comment: In principle, you can have a many-sorted logic language, wuth e.g. variables **x1,y1, ...** standing for individuals, variables **x2, y2, ...** standing for couples, and so on. Thus we may have **∀x1 P(x1)** and **∃x2 Q(x2)**. It is simply more ... complicated.

Comment: I don't think quantification works that way.  R (a,b) means that the pair (a,b) satisfies R, or is an element of the relation R.  nested quantification says something subtley different, I think. plus the nesting could go both ways in classic logic.  to get something more "Natural" look to constructive logic or type theory?

Comment: This seems like it's going to turn out to be largely opinion-based. All logical formalization is an encoding. How far this encoding is from how people think depends on the people thinking ...

Comment: Ben-Yami argues in [Logic and Natural Language](https://publications.ceu.edu/sites/default/files/publications/logic-natural-language-revised-version_0.pdf) that Frege's predicate calculus is altogether inadequate for natural languages: "*the  way  reference  is 
incorporated in the calculus is fundamentally different from the way it is incorporated in  natural  language,  and  that  as  a  result  predication  and  quantification  in  the  two systems   are   profoundly   dissimilar.   Consequently, reference, predication and quantification in natural  language  cannot  be  understood...*"

Comment: if you look hard enough at this problem it turns out to be a matter of recursion, so the question more or less turns out to be "are natural languages recursive?"  Chomsky et al. argue that recursion is the fundamental distinguishing property of natural language.  Others say not.  I gather it's one of the hotter issues in linguistics these days.

Comment: Logic itself is not particularly natural to think about. Formalization is unnatural and modern. So whether nested quantifiers (or really a sequence of quantifiers) is equivalent formally to a single quantifier over tuples is a formal, mathematical game. I find separating the quantifiers more natural, but I suppose other might find the tuple idea more natural.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to argue that nested quantification is not natural.  Quite early languages have articles and combinations of moods that serve the purpose of [quantifying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit_pronouns_and_determiners#Indefinite_and_absolute_negative_phrases).  We naturally say 'A dog is (by nature) four-legged', or, if we own Champ the amputee, 'Dogs are not necessarily four-legged'.  There is not a thing that marks quantification, but as a consequence of mood ('by nature', 'necessarily') it is grammatically present.

Since we have verb phrases that reference other verb phrases, then, successions of moods result in nested quantifications.  "Should there be a distance delta given, a fraction epsilon must be found which..." or in a well inflected language "I give (subjunctive) delta, you find (imperative) epsilon within it to..." encodes equally well the constant nested quantification in analytics "For every distance delta there is a lesser epsilon such that...".

Aristotle moves forward from here with his framing using pronouns of quantity.  I think this was not natural to his language, as such things were still generally phrased by [hypotheticals](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Apart%3D4%3Achapter%3D57%3Asection%3D157) with protasis and apodosis in different moods.

It can be argued that Aristotelian forms are not quantified, but it is clearer to say that his 'No', 'One' and 'Some' are in fact quantifiers, just less simple and more natural to human usage.  And even if 'All' is in some way not identical to universal quantification, it captures the itent.

But if you look at what proceeds from Aristotle's own language you easily get them nested "All the children of some mothers will be talented."  Some forms of this in older Greek are *literally* nested in a [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_grammar#Definite_article) similar to "The(nominative) The(genitive) some mothers(genitive) [all] children(nominative) talented will-be."

Our abstract Universal and Existential forms may therefore be less natural than other earlier forms of quantification.  But parameterization of the form you propose comes into the argument much, much later, when people start trying to reify relations, and does not find natural forms in language even in English and French, where it was first injected.  So it is hard to argue that it would be more natural than nesting.

So, based on classical languages, I would claim that a very thorough form of modal logic would be the most natural way to think about quantification, even though it might be more complex syntactically than our two quantifiers, but that nesting is a natural artifact of any representation of quantification.

It is hard to see how a system where "possibly (delta > 0) implies necessarily (epsilon in [0, delta] and...)" stands in for "for all delta > 0, there exists an epsilon in [0, delta] such that..." can be processed as smoothly, but it captures the idea of 'ask and answer' more naturally than the traditional form.